# Make a div with fixed position

Tags: javascript, css

how to make a div with fixed position at top Of the page that work in all browsers like IE

Answer (score 2):

A div that will always stay at the top of the page (in this case, 5px from the top):

CSS:

```
.mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;  /* or however far you want it from the top of the page */
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="mydiv">this will always be 5px from the top of the page</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`foo { position: fixed !important; position: absolute /* fallback for IE6 */; }`